# Multiply all values in dataframe with a number from another dataframe where name is the same

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I want to multiply one column with the values in another dataframe where the names in another column match.

df1

```
0 'NOK' 10
1 'NOK' 20
2 'SEK' 30
3 'USD' 40
```

df2

```
0 'NOK' 2
1 'SEK' 1
2 'USD' 7
```

I want `df1` to be extended to

df1

```
0 'NOK' 20
1 'NOK' 40
2 'SEK' 30
3 'USD' 280
```

My dataframes include many currencies, so a general solution is searched for.

I hardcoded each name like this, but I want a general code.

```
df1['test']=0
df1.loc[df1[1]=='NOK','test']=df1[1][df1[1]=='NOK']*df2[df2[1]=='NOK]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with `set_index` and `mul`:

```
(df1.set_index([1])[2]
    .mul(df2.set_index([1])[2])
 .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
       1    2
0  'NOK'   20
1  'NOK'   40
2  'SEK'   30
3  'USD'  280
```

Comment: Thanks, I run into a problem as my df2 includes one currency not seen in df1. The length of the resulting column is then longer.

Comment: I don't think that's a problem, but you should reflect that in your sample data.